# Typesafe of generics in Visitor and Strategy Pattern

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I'm trying to create a `Visitor<T>` that returns a certain `strategy` for an instanceof object.
It already works, but I cannot get the `Generics` typesafe. What am I missing i the following code:

```
class Base;
class Foo extends Base;
class Bar extends Base;

interface Visitor<T> {
    T visit (Foo foo);
    T visit (Bar bar);
}

interface Strategy<T> {
    void action(T obj);
}

class FooStrategy implements Strategy<Foo> {
    @Override
    void action(Foo foo) {
        //perform strategy action on foo
    }
}

//References to generic type Strategy<T> should be parameterized
class MyVisitor implements Visitor<Strategy> {

    //References to generic type Strategy<T> should be parameterized
    @Override
    Strategy visit(Foo foo) {
        return new FooStrategy();
    }

    //References to generic type MyStrategy<T> should be parameterized
    @Override
    Strategy visit(Bar bar) {
        return new BarStrategy();
    }
}
```

In the class `MyVisitor` eclipse keeps complaining that `Strategy<T>` should be parameterized. What am I missing to make this generic construct `typesafe`?

**Update:**

I want to use it like this:

```
        Visitor<Strategy> visitor = new MyVisitor();
        Strategy strat = drawable.accept(visitor);

        //use the strategy
        Base object; //may be a Foo or Bar or whatever
        strat.action(object);
```

Comment: I don't think this is _quite_ the visitor pattern. For example, your `Visitor`'s methods should return `void` and your `Strategy`s should accept a `Visitor`. Consider not using the visitor pattern at all, however: [The Visitor Pattern](http://java.dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-visitor), see "Watch Out for the Downsides" at the end of the article.

Comment: @membersound Did you found a solution for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put a `? extends Base` to the type parameter to indicate that it's a strategy of whatever type you don't care, but it must be a subclass of Base.

```
class MyVisitor implements Visitor<Strategy<? extends Base>> {
  @Override
  Strategy<? extends Base> visit(Foo foo) {
    return new FooStrategy();
  }
  @Override
  Strategy<? extends Base> visit(Bar bar) {
    return new BarStrategy();
  }
}
```

```
    Visitor<Strategy<? extends Base>> visitor = new MyVisitor();
    Strategy<? extends Base> strat = drawable.accept(visitor);
```

However, you are not allowed to call a strategy like that:

```
    //use the strategy
    Base object; //may be a Foo or Bar or whatever
    strat.action(object);  // <--- error.
```

because the action method effectively has a signature of

```
<U extends Base> void action(U object);
```

i.e. the type of the argument may *require* an arbitrary subclass of Base, and the only type which can be passed to any arbitrary subclass of Base is `null`.

To solve this, simply make FooStrategy and BarStrategy implement `Strategy<Base>`:

```
class FooStrategy implements Strategy<Base> { void action(Base obj) { ... } }
class BarStrategy implements Strategy<Base> { void action(Base obj) { ... } }

class MyVisitor implements Visitor<Strategy<Base>> {
  @Override
  Strategy<Base> visit(Foo foo) {
    return new FooStrategy();
  }
  @Override
  Strategy<Base> visit(Bar bar) {
    return new BarStrategy();
  }
}

Visitor<Strategy<Base>> visitor = new MyVisitor();
Strategy<Base> strat = drawable.accept(visitor);

Base object;
strat.action(object);
```

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to mention that Foo and Bar are indeed related!

Comment: Hmm this solves the complains about typesafety, but I cannot use it in my code then. Please have a look how I make use of the code updated above. If I use `? extends Base  it then complains that  `strat.action(object);` is not applicable for the argument. And that I should change `action(T)` to `action(Base)`.

Comment: @membersound: You need to change *all* bare `Strategy` with `Strategy<? extends Base>`.

Comment: I did, but still complains about not being applicable for the arguments. It's suggested to change `interface Strategy<T> { void delete(T); }` to `delete(Base)`.

Comment: @membersound: See update. What you want is impossible to do in compile-time.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a Visitor. And even if it were, this is not a correct use for one. Visitor uses double dispatch; this does not have that.